# WPF Button ControlTemplate Height binding returns NaN

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to dynamically set the corner radius of WPF buttons to half of the buttons' height, such that the ends are rounded entirely.

The entry in the Window resources looks like the following, however the `CornerRadius` binding doesn't bind, and passes `NaN` to the value converter.

I've tried replacing the `Binding` with a `TemplateBinding` to no avail. Snoop shows an error on that `CornerRadius` property, being set as `NaN`. Am I missing something obvious here?

```cs
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#FFFEFEFF" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Height,Converter={StaticResource HalfConverter}}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
...
```

Comment: Bind to ActualHeight instead of Height.

Comment: @Clemens Ah! That was easy. I think I was not far off myself, looking through other properties and finding `RenderSize`. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it with thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of binding to the control's `Height` (which is `Double.NaN` unless it is explicitly set), you should bind to its `ActualHeight` property:

```
CornerRadius="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                       Converter={StaticResource HalfConverter}}">
```